# pg_dump of table and its transitive dependencies

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Sometimes I'd like to export just a single table and its dependencies, so I can do some experiments with it on a test database. Is there a way to do that, other than dumping the full db schema with `pg_dump` and any table dependencies manually?

For example let's say I have a table `employees` which has a single foreign key to `companies.id` and uses a few custom enums or other types. Let's also assume `companies` is self-contained, i.e. does not depend on anything else. So what I'd like to have is some way of dumping  `employees`, both schema and all (or a subset) of the data and automatically get the required type definitons, and the schema for `company` as well as all referencered entries.

Is there a way to do this easily with `pg_dump` or some other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> uses a few custom enums or other types.

No. That's because those enum types can be used in different tables and such. PostgreSQL doesn't have a dependency tracker to make this work. The only exception to this that I know is sequences, `-t` will recreate sequences.

That said, if you recreate the database once, you only ever have to run `pg_dump -t employees -c`, the `-c` flag will drop the table and recreate it. This will unfortunately not work with foreign key constraints pointing to `employees`